# Training model from logits and checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I am new in tensor flow and I am trying to train the mobile net_v1. To do that, I first created the tfrecords' file for multi-class from a txt file.( example : namefile label1 label2 ...)

```
import sys, os
import tensorflow as tf 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# function

def load_image(addr):
    # read an image and resize to (224, 224)
    # cv2 load images as BGR, convert it to RGB
    img = cv2.imread(addr)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    return img

def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[*value]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def loadData(inputs):
    addrs = []
    labels = []
    f = open(inputs, 'r')
    data = [ln.split(' ') for ln in f ]
    f.close()
    print(data)
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        addrs.append(data[i][0].rstrip())
        l = []
        for j in range(1,len(data[i])):
            if(data[i][j].rstrip().isdigit() == True):
                l.append(int(data[i][j].rstrip()))

        print(l)
        labels.append(l)

    return addrs, labels

def CreateTrainFile(input_filename, train_filename,):
    path = '/home/rd/Documents/RD2/Databases/Faces/'
    # load file and label
    train_addrs, train_labels = loadData(input_filename)
    print(train_labels)
    # open the TFRecords file
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(train_filename)
    for i in range(len(train_addrs)):
        # print how many images are saved every 1000 images
        if not i % 1000:
            print('Train data: {}/{}'.format(i, len(train_addrs)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        # Load the image
        img = load_image(train_addrs[i])
        label = train_labels[i]
        print('label : ', _int64_feature(label))
        # Create a feature
        feature = {'train/label': _int64_feature(label),
                'train/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring()))}
        # Create an example protocol buffer
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

        # Serialize to string and write on the file
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()

# open the TFRecords file
def CreateValidationFile(val_filename):

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(val_filename)
    for i in range(len(val_addrs)):
        # print how many images are saved every 1000 images
        if not i % 1000:
            print('Val data: {}/{}'.format(i, len(val_addrs)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        # Load the image
        img = load_image(val_addrs[i])
        label = val_labels[i]
        # Create a feature
        feature = {'val/label': _int64_feature(label),
                'val/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring()))}
        # Create an example protocol buffer
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
        # Serialize to string and write on the file
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()

# open the TFRecords file
def CreateTestFile(test_filename):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(test_filename)
    for i in range(len(test_addrs)):
        # print how many images are saved every 1000 images
        if not i % 1000:
            print('Test data: {}/{}'.format(i, len(test_addrs)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        # Load the image
        img = load_image(test_addrs[i])
        label = test_labels[i]
        # Create a feature
        feature = {'test/label': _int64_feature(label),
                'test/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring()))}
        # Create an example protocol buffer
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
        # Serialize to string and write on the file
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()

def ReadRecordFileTrain(data_path):
    #data_path = 'train.tfrecords'  # address to save the hdf5 file
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        feature = {'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
        # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)
        # Define a reader and read the next record
        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
        # Decode the record read by the reader
        features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
        # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
        image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)

        # Cast label data into int32
        label = tf.cast(features['train/label'], tf.int32)
        # Reshape image data into the original shape
        image = tf.reshape(image, [224, 224, 3])

        # Any preprocessing here ...

        # Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors
        images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=2, capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)
        return images, labels
def main():
    train_filename = 'train.tfrecords'  # address to save the TFRecords file
    #test_filename = 'test.tfrecords'  # address to save the TFRecords file
    #val_filename = 'val.tfrecords'  # address to save the TFRecords file
    CreateTrainFile("data.txt", train_filename)
main()
```

and to read the tf records :

```
def ReadRecordFileTrain(data_path):
    #data_path = 'train.tfrecords'  # address to save the hdf5 file
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        feature = {'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([2], tf.int64)}
        # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)
        # Define a reader and read the next record
        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
        # Decode the record read by the reader
        features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
        # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
        image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)
        print('label1 :', features['train/label'] )
        # Cast label data into int32
        label = tf.cast(features['train/label'], tf.int32)
        print('label load:', label)
        # Reshape image data into the original shape
        image = tf.reshape(image, [224, 224, 3])

        # Any preprocessing here ...

        # Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors
        images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=2, capacity=30, num_threads=1)
        return images, labels
```

I suppose it works but I am not sure ( I don't have any errors when I called these functions.)
Then, I load the model and its weight. Call the loss function and try to start the training, but it fails at this moment.

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    # size of the folder
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 224, 224, 3])

    # load dataset
    images, labels = ReadRecordFileTrain('train.tfrecords')
    print('load dataset done')
    print('labels = ', labels)
    print('data = ', images)
    print(tf.shape(labels))

    # load network
    network, end_points= mobilenet.mobilenet_v1(images, num_classes=2, depth_multiplier=0.25 )

    print('load network done')
    print('network : ', network)

    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=["MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1"])

    load_checkpoint = "modele_mobilenet_v1_025/mobilenet_v1_0.25_224.ckpt"
    init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(load_checkpoint, variables_to_restore)
    print('custom network done')



    # Specify the loss function:
    tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels, network)

    total_loss = tf.losses.get_total_loss()
    #tf.scalar_summary('losses/total_loss', total_loss)

    # Specify the optimization scheme:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.001)

    # create_train_op that ensures that when we evaluate it to get the loss,
    # the update_ops are done and the gradient updates are computed.
    train_tensor = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)
    print('loss and optimizer chosen')
    # Actually runs training.
    save_checkpoint = 'model/modelcheck'

    # start training
    learning = slim.learning.train(train_tensor, save_checkpoint, init_fn=init_fn, number_of_steps=1000)
```

The error message :

```
label1 : Tensor("ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_train/label:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
label load: Tensor("Cast:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
load dataset done
labels =  Tensor("batch:1", shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
data =  Tensor("batch:0", shape=(2, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
load network done
network :  Tensor("MobilenetV1/Logits/SpatialSqueeze:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
custom network done
loss and optimizer chosen
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,2] rhs shape= [1,1,256,1]
    [[Node: save_1/Assign_109 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights, save_1/RestoreV2_109)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 106, in <module>
    main()
File "test.py", line 103, in main
    learning = slim.learning.train(train_tensor, save_checkpoint, init_fn=init_fn, number_of_steps=1000)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 725, in train
    master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess:
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 960, in managed_session
    self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 788, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 949, in managed_session
    start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 706, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
    init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 256, in prepare_session
    config=config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 188, in _restore_checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1457, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,2] rhs shape= [1,1,256,1]
    [[Node: save_1/Assign_109 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights, save_1/RestoreV2_109)]]

Caused by op 'save_1/Assign_109', defined at:
File "test.py", line 106, in <module>
    main()
File "test.py", line 103, in main
    learning = slim.learning.train(train_tensor, save_checkpoint, init_fn=init_fn, number_of_steps=1000)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 642, in train
    saver = saver or tf_saver.Saver()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1056, in __init__
    self.build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1086, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 691, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 419, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(tensors, shapes))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 155, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 270, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 47, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,256,2] rhs shape= [1,1,256,1]
    [[Node: save_1/Assign_109 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1/weights, save_1/RestoreV2_109)]]
```

I don't understand where the problem comes from and how to solve it.

Comment: I used to get this error when my model saved in the model directory has conflicts with my current running model. Try deleting your model directory and start training again.

Comment: Thanks, it solves this problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match.
>   lhs shape= [1,1,256,2] rhs shape= [1,1,256,1]

I used to get this error when my model saved in the model directory has conflicts with my current running model. Try deleting your model directory and start training again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to solve the error but now, when I want to execute it with a tf.Session it failed. I was wondering if the problem comes from my graph or am I doing something wrong in the tf.Session ?

```
def evaluation(logits, labels):

    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
# Operation comparing prediction with true label
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))

# Operation calculating the accuracy of the predictions
        accuracy =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# Summary operation for the accuracy
#tf.scalar_summary('train_accuracy', accuracy)
        return accuracy


g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    # size of the folder
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 224, 224, 3])

    # load dataset
    images, labels = ReadRecordFileTrain('train.tfrecords')
    print('load dataset done')
    print('labels = ', labels)
    print('data = ', images)
    print(tf.shape(labels))

    # load network
    network, end_points= mobilenet.mobilenet_v1(images, num_classes=2, depth_multiplier=0.25 )

    print('load network done')
    print('network : ', network)

    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=["MobilenetV1/Logits/Conv2d_1c_1x1"])

    load_checkpoint = "modele_mobilenet_v1_025/mobilenet_v1_0.25_224.ckpt"
    init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(load_checkpoint, variables_to_restore)
    print('custom network done')



    # Specify the loss function:
    tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels, network)

    total_loss = tf.losses.get_total_loss()
    #tf.scalar_summary('losses/total_loss', total_loss)

    # Specify the optimization scheme:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.001)

    # create_train_op that ensures that when we evaluate it to get the loss,
    # the update_ops are done and the gradient updates are computed.
    train_tensor = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)
    print('loss and optimizer chosen')
    # Actually runs training.
    save_checkpoint = 'model/modelcheck'

    # start training
    learning = slim.learning.train(train_tensor, save_checkpoint, init_fn=init_fn, number_of_steps=1000)

    accuracy = evaluation(network, labels)


with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    sess.run(network)
    print('network load')
    sess.run(total_loss)
    sess.run(accuracy)
    sess.run(train_tensor)
    sess.run(learning)
```

The error :

```
label1 : Tensor("ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_train/label:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
label load: Tensor("Cast:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
load dataset done
labels =  Tensor("batch:1", shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32)
data =  Tensor("batch:0", shape=(4, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
load network done
network :  Tensor("MobilenetV1/Logits/SpatialSqueeze:0", shape=(4, 2), dtype=float32)
custom network done
loss and optimizer chosen
end of graph
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta
    [[Node: MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
File "test.py", line 105, in main
    sess.run(network)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta
    [[Node: MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta)]]

Caused by op 'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/read', defined at:
File "test.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
File "test.py", line 67, in main
    network, end_points= mobilenet.mobilenet_v1(images, num_classes=2, depth_multiplier=0.25 )
File "/home/rd/Documents/RD2/users/Ludovic/tensorflow_mobilenet/mobilenet_v1.py", line 301, in mobilenet_v1
    conv_defs=conv_defs)
File "/home/rd/Documents/RD2/users/Ludovic/tensorflow_mobilenet/mobilenet_v1.py", line 228, in mobilenet_v1_base
    scope=end_point)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1891, in separable_convolution2d
    outputs = normalizer_fn(outputs, **normalizer_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 528, in batch_norm
    outputs = layer.apply(inputs, training=is_training)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 320, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 286, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py", line 125, in build
    trainable=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1049, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 948, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 349, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1389, in wrapped_custom_getter
    *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 275, in variable_getter
    variable_getter=functools.partial(getter, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 228, in _add_variable
    trainable=trainable and self.trainable)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1389, in wrapped_custom_getter
    *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1334, in layer_variable_getter
    return _model_variable_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1326, in _model_variable_getter
    custom_getter=getter, use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py", line 262, in model_variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py", line 217, in variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1334, in layer_variable_getter
    return _model_variable_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1326, in _model_variable_getter
    custom_getter=getter, use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py", line 262, in model_variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py", line 217, in variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 341, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 714, in _get_single_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 197, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 316, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1338, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta
    [[Node: MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MobilenetV1/Conv2d_3_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta)]]
```